# Jquery UI tabs failing to reference on ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I am using jquery ui tabs feature in my page. I am making an ajax call from first tab on a button click. But my ajax call is disabling the jquery ui tabs feature if i reclick on the button in first tab (Jquery UI tabs getting disabled on 2nd click and sometime on 3rd or 4th...clicks as well). Getting "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function" error. Looking for reason and fix. See my below page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<title>Home</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();

        $("#testButton").on("click", function(event) {
            $.ajax({
                url : "http://localhost:8080/Crudwebapp/getTestPage.do",
                type : "GET"
            }).done(function(result) {
                hideStuff();
                $("#parentDiv").html(result);
            });

        });

        function hideStuff() {
            $("body > div[id='header']").hide();
            $("body > div[id='tabs']").hide();
            $("body > div[id='footer']").hide();
        }
    });


</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="parentDiv"></div>
    <div id="header">
        <h2>Test Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Test1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Test2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Test3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-4">Test4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <input id="testButton" type="button" value="Click">
        </div>

        <div id="tabs-2"></div>
        <div id="tabs-3"></div>
        <div id="tabs-4"></div>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <h2>Test Footer</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller code:

```
package com.xyz.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/getTestPage.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getTestPage() {
        return new ModelAndView("test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't read through all of your code (you might consider creating a test page with only the relevant code in it), you're rewriting the HTML on your click event handlers.  `tabs()` doesn't get applied to that HTML as far as I can tell.  Also, you're not using `$(document).ready()`, so jquery may be trying to call the `tabs()` function from a context before your document (in this case, the jquery-ui.js) file was fully loaded.  That could be why you're getting the error.

I'd suggest first replacing this:

```
$(function() {
```

with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

This is the standard way to use jQuery.  Then, if you're still having trouble, you'll want to call `tabs()` again after changing the HTML.

Comment: Its still not working using $(document).ready(function() {}. I have updated my code in the question with a similar test scenario. Please look and suggest.

Comment: The only way I can recreate that error is if the reference to jquery-ui is missing.  Perhaps you can double check your code and make sure that the references are the same as the ones you've published here.

Comment: Yes. When i crosscheck the html generated on aajx call it contains the jquery ui references. I am trying to understand why i am getting the reference error at random. Does it got anything to do with the placement of ajax html response? And also the error occurs most frequently in chrome and less frequently in IE11. Could it be a cross browser issue?

Comment: I posted a new answer that I'm convinced is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add this as another answer, since it is entirely different from my previous one (and is the root cause of the problem as well).  I was able to replicate the problem last night on a test page.

Your problem is due to an intermittent availability issue at `https://code.jquery.com`, resulting in slow response times, sometimes slow enough to time out your application.  If you don't want to depend on jquery.com being available for your application to work, then either download your version of the jquery files to your website and reference the downloaded files, or consider using [google web hosting](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/).